# jquery-mobile: silentScroll not working from initPage

Tags: jquery-mobile

I want to silently scroll the window when the page is completely loaded, so I call silentScroll inside the initPage listener. However, it doesn't work, no scrolling.

```
$('#mainPage').live( 'pageinit', initPage);

function initPage() {
    $.mobile.fixedToolbars.setTouchToggleEnabled(false);
    $.mobile.silentScroll(800);
    ....
```

The only way I can get it to work is to call it via setTimeout, but why? The page should be ready when pageinit is executed, referring to the jqm docs on http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/events.html.

With this, automatic scroll works, but it's ugly:

```
setTimeout(function(){$.mobile.silentScroll(8000);}, 1000);  // scroll after 1 sec
```

Executing `$.mobile.silentScroll(8000);` in Firebug / Chrome dev tools also works ok, just not in initPage. When I display an js alert in initPage, it's being shown. But the scrolling is just not being executed properly. Maybe a jqm bug?

Comment: maybe try this syntax for the callback  $('#mainPage').live('pageinit', function() {
        $.mobile.fixedToolbars.setTouchToggleEnabled(false);
        $.mobile.silentScroll(800);
    });

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Detailed answer to this question here:
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/3461

Comment: Use `pageshow`. If you only want it to scroll the first viewing then set a flag.

Comment: I tried pageshow as well, but it didn't work either. The page, which is longer, is built via JS, DOM manipulation using jqm's appendTo(). Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: were you able to figure it out @Mathias Lin . I am facing the same issuw